Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin, but I already using latest version
I'm already using the latest version of Kotlin Gradle but I keep getting this error:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}



│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                            │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update │
│ /Users/sinamn75/Documents/NabzAfzar/NabzAfzar_flutter/android/build.gradle:                       │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'     

I used a lot of different versions on projects and packages but nothing seems to work.

How about changing the line to the suggested one: ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'?  version 1.8.20 is definitely not the latest version (at the moment of writing, the latest version is 1.9.23): https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details

See also this

Does this answer your question? ext.kotlin_version = <'latest version'> error on Flutter

@Raptor I already did, same error

@Leviathan No did not help, I already did everything about changing versions everywhere

Have you tried to clean your gradle cache folder?
How to clear gradle cache?
I had similar problem, cleaning cache solve it

OMG, it seems a bug in flutter, I was entering my keystore password wrong and it pointed to something completely different,
It was never about kotlin version, It was about keystore password...

clear cache & retry please
